# HTML get URL, Radio Button Group, javascript parse, set buttons value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a survey on a page with 5 questions. Each question is made up of a 0 - 10 scale. each one is a radio button in a group. I pass this form data to another page and i get your typical get URL. Im parsing this with javascript and can get each groups value. example get URL i have is this 
  `/graphs.html?happiness=8&enthusiastic=7&resilient=9`

I now have the value into a var

```
function processScore() {
    var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
    var temp = parameters[0].split("=");
    h = unescape(temp[1]);
    temp = parameters[1].split("=");
    e = unescape(temp[1]);
    temp = parameters[2].split("=");
    r = unescape(temp[1]);
    temp = parameters[3].split("=");
    o = unescape(temp[1]);
    temp = parameters[4].split("=");
    w = unescape(temp[1]);
    document.getElementById("happiness").innerHTML = h;
    document.getElementById("enthusiastic").innerHTML = e;
    document.getElementById("resilient").innerHTML = r;
    document.getElementById("optimistic").innerHTML = o;
    document.getElementById("wellness").innerHTML = w;
}
processScore();
```

I want to recreate the same survey, with their answer checkmarked on the radio button but cant figure out how to do it.

so i am trying to set a radio button as checked within a group based on a value i have in a javascript var i got from an html get URL.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve at all. Can you provide a complete example with the form and the js so we can see what you already tried and what's not working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

im not sure how else to say it. I have a radio button group of 11 buttons. i want to set one of them as checked based on the data being passed in a get URL.

I have a form with radio button groups. the form is just 5 questions numbered 0 - 10. each one is a radio button. when they hit submit i get a standard get URL like `/graphs.html?happiness=8&enthusiastic=7&resilient=9`. I am able to parse this URL with the javascript above. 
I want to recreate the form, but each question i want their answer checkmarked. so for question 1, happiness, their answer was 8. so i want the radio button related to 8 checked. and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you're markup is like, so it's hard to say. But assuming happiness refers to the container of each question with radio buttons inside, something along these lines might work?

```
function processScore() {
    var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
    var temp = parameters[0].split("=");
    h = unescape(temp[1]);
    temp = parameters[1].split("=");
    e = unescape(temp[1]);
    temp = parameters[2].split("=");
    r = unescape(temp[1]);
    temp = parameters[3].split("=");
    o = unescape(temp[1]);
    temp = parameters[4].split("=");
    w = unescape(temp[1]);
    document.querySelectorAll("happiness input[type='radio']")[parseInt(h)].checked = true;
    document.getElementById("enthusiastic")[parseInt(e)].checked = true;
    document.getElementById("resilient input[type='radio']")[parseInt(r)].checked = true;
    document.getElementById("optimistic input[type='radio']")[parseInt(0)].checked = true;
    document.getElementById("wellness input[type='radio']")[parseInt(w)].checked = true;
}
processScore();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is where i am right now. I just saw your answer and will attempt to try that. however i dont fully understand it yet. There is a section in my code that simply parses the URL to make sure its still doing it right. man, i think i should go back to networking and leave this programming stuff up to someone else. LOL

```
    {<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <style>
            #happiness, #enthusiastic, #resilient, #optimistic, #wellness { color: white; background-color:black; padding-left:8px; padding-right:8px; }
    .titlebox {
        width:40%;
        height:3%;
        padding:3px;
        border:1px solid #000000;
        background-color:#EFEFEF;
        left: auto;
        right: auto;
        position: relative;
        }
    .title {
        text-align:center;
        margin:auto;
        font-family:"calibri";
        font-size:28px;
        }
    .questions {
        text-align: left;
        margin: auto;
        font-family: "calibri";
        font-size: 23px;
        display: inline-block;
        }
    #wrap {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        }

    #content {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        }
    .underline {
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        width: 95%;
        margin: auto;
        }
    .scaleleft {
        color: rgb(89,89,89);
        font-size: 21px;
        font-family: "calibri";
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 10px;
        }
    .scalecenter {
        color: rgb(89,89,89);
        font-size: 21px;
        font-family: "calibri";
        text-align: center;
        }
    .scaleright {
        color: rgb(89,89,89);
        font-size: 21px;
        font-family: "calibri";
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 10px;
        }
    .footer {
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        font-family: "calibri";
        font-size: 19px;
        }
    .page {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow: scroll;
        <!-- overflow: hidden; -->
        max-height: 500px;
        <!-- line-height: 1.2em; -->
        }
    .body {
        text-align: center
        }
    .table {
        width: 100%;
        }
    .numbersPlacementRight {
        font-size: 19px;
        font-family: "calibri";
        text-align: right;
        }
    .numbersPlacementCenter {
        font-size: 19px;
        font-family: "calibri";
        text-align: center;
        }
    .numbersPlacementLeft {
        font-size: 19px;
        font-family: "calibri";
        text-align: left;
        }
    .button {
        size: 25;
        value: "Submit"
        }
    .box {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 960px;
        height: 500px;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #DDD;
        overflow: hidden;
        }
    .button {
        height: 40px;
        width: 80px;
        }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body class="page">
    <div class="titlebox title"><b>Wellness Survey</b></div>

    <div>
               <p>
                  <div class="questions">1.  On average, during the last 7 DAYS, how happy have you felt?</div>
                  </br>
                  </br>
                  <table class="table ">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "happiness" value = "0" id = "H0"/> <label for = "H0">0</label></td>
                        <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "happiness" value = "1" id = "H1"/> <label for = "H1">1</label></td>
                        <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "happiness" value = "2" id = "H2"/> <label for = "H3">2</label></td>
                        <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "happiness" value = "3" id = "H3"/> <label for = "H3">3</label></td>
                        <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "happiness" value = "4" id = "H4"/> <label for = "H4">4</label></td>
                        <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "happiness" value = "5" id = "H5"/> <label for = "H5">5</label></td>
                        <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "happiness" value = "6" id = "H6"/> <label for = "H6">6</label></td>
                        <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "happiness" value = "7" id = "H7"/> <label for = "H7">7</label></td>
                        <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "happiness" value = "8" id = "H8"/> <label for = "H8">8</label></td>
                        <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "happiness" value = "9" id = "H9"/> <label for = "H9">9</label></td>
                        <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "happiness" value = "10" id = "H10"/> <label for = "H10">10</label></td>
                        <td>&nbsp</td>
                    </tr>
                </table> 
                  <div class="underline"></div>
                </p>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="scaleleft">Not at all<br />happy</td>
                        <td class="scalecenter">Midly<br />happy</td>
                        <td class="scalecenter">Moderately<br />happy</td>
                        <td class="scalecenter">Markedly<br />happy</td>
                        <td class="scaleright">Extremely<br />happy</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </br>
                </br>
               <p>
                  <div class="questions">2.  On average, during the last 7 DAYS, how enthusiastic have you felt?</div>
                  </br>
                  </br>
                 <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "enthusiastic" value = "0" id = "E0" /><label for = "E0">0</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "enthusiastic" value = "1" id = "E1"/><label for = "E1">1</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "enthusiastic" value = "2" id = "E2"/><label for = "E2">2</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "enthusiastic" value = "3" id = "E3"/><label for = "E3">3</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "enthusiastic" value = "4" id = "E4"/><label for = "E4">4</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "enthusiastic" value = "5" id = "E5"/><label for = "E5">5</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "enthusiastic" value = "6" id = "E6"/><label for = "E6">6</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "enthusiastic" value = "7" id = "E7"/><label for = "E7">7</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "enthusiastic" value = "8" id = "E8"/><label for = "E8">8</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "enthusiastic" value = "9" id = "E9"/><label for = E9">9</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "enthusiastic" value = "10" id = "E10"/><label for = "E10">10</label></td>
                      <td>&nbsp</td>
                     </tr>
                </table>
                  <div class="underline"></div>
                </p>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="scaleleft">Not at all<br />enthusiastic</td>
                        <td class="scalecenter">Midly<br />enthusiastic</td>
                        <td class="scalecenter">Moderately<br />enthusiastic</td>
                        <td class="scalecenter">Markedly<br />enthusiastic</td>
                        <td class="scaleright">Extremely<br />enthusiastic</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </br>
                </br>
                <p>
                  <div class="questions">3.  On average, during the last 7 DAYS, how resilient have you felt?</div>
                  </br>
                  </br>
                 <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "resilient" value = "0" id = "R0"/><label for = "R0">0</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "resilient" value = "1" id = "R1"/><label for = "R1">1</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "resilient" value = "2" id = "R2"/><label for = "R2">2</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "resilient" value = "3" id = "R3"/><label for = "R3">3</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "resilient" value = "4" id = "R4"/><label for = "R4">4</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "resilient" value = "5" id = "R5"/><label for = "R5">5</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "resilient" value = "6" id = "R6"/><label for = "R6">6</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "resilient" value = "7" id = "R7"/><label for = "R7">7</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "resilient" value = "8" id = "R8"/><label for = "R8">8</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "resilient" value = "9" id = "R9"/><label for = "R9">9</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "resilient" value = "10" id = "R10"/><label for = "R10">10</label></td>
                      <td>&nbsp</td>
                     </tr>
                    </table>
                  <div class="underline"></div>
                </p>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="scaleleft">Not at all<br />resilient</td>
                        <td class="scalecenter">Midly<br />resilient</td>
                        <td class="scalecenter">Moderately<br />resilient</td>
                        <td class="scalecenter">Markedly<br />resilient</td>
                        <td class="scaleright">Extremely<br />resilient</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </br>
                </br>
                <p>
                  <div class="questions">4.  On average, during the last 7 DAYS, how optimistic have you felt?</div>
                  </br>
                  </br>
                 <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "optimistic" value = "0" id = "O0" /> <label for = "O0">0</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "optimistic" value = "1" id = "O1"/> <label for = "O1">1</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "optimistic" value = "2" id = "O2"/> <label for = "O2">2</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "optimistic" value = "3" id = "O3"/> <label for = "O3">3</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "optimistic" value = "4" id = "O4"/> <label for = "O4">4</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "optimistic" value = "5" id = "O5"/> <label for = "O5">5</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "optimistic" value = "6" id = "O6"/> <label for = "O6">6</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "optimistic" value = "7" id = "O7"/> <label for = "O7">7</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "optimistic" value = "8" id = "O8"/> <label for = "O8">8</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "optimistic" value = "9" id = "O9"/> <label for = "O9">9</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "optimistic" value = "10" id = "O10"/> <label for = "O10">10</label></td>
                      <td>&nbsp</td>
                     </tr>
                    </table>
                  <div class="underline"></div>
                </p>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="scaleleft">Not at all<br />optimistic</td>
                        <td class="scalecenter">Midly<br />optimistic</td>
                        <td class="scalecenter">Moderately<br />optimistic</td>
                        <td class="scalecenter">Markedly<br />optimistic</td>
                        <td class="scaleright">Extremely<br />optimistic</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </br>
                </br>
                <p>
                  <div class="questions">5.  On average, during the last 7 DAYS, how would you rate your mental wellness?</div>
                  </br>
                  </br>
                 <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "wellness" value = "0" id = "W0" /> <label for = "W0">0</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "wellness" value = "1" id = "W1"/> <label for = "W1">1</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "wellness" value = "2" id = "W2"/> <label for = "W2">2</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "wellness" value = "3" id = "W3"/> <label for = "W3">3</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "wellness" value = "4" id = "W4"/> <label for = "W4">4</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "wellness" value = "5" id = "W5"/> <label for = "W5">5</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "wellness" value = "6" id = "W6"/> <label for = "W6">6</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "wellness" value = "7" id = "W7"/> <label for = "W7">7</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "wellness" value = "8" id = "W8"/> <label for = "W8">8</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "wellness" value = "9" id = "W9"/> <label for = "W9">9</label></td>
                      <td class="numbersPlacementCenter"><input type = "radio" name = "wellness" value = "10" id = "W10"/> <label for = "W10">10</label></td>
                      <td>&nbsp</td>
                     </tr>
                    </table>
                  <div class="underline"></div>
                </p>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="scaleleft">Not at all<br />good</td>
                        <td class="scalecenter">Midly<br />good</td>
                        <td class="scalecenter">Moderately<br />good</td>
                        <td class="scalecenter">Markedly<br />good</td>
                        <td class="scaleright">Extremely<br />good</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </br>
                </br>

                    <!-- <form action="https://wild5wellness.weebly.com/hero-survey-results.html">
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
                    </form> -->

                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </form>

                </br>
                </br>
                </br>
                <div class="footer">Copyright 2017, Dr. Saundra Jain and Dr. Rakesh Jain</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <h2>Testing: </h2>
        <p><b>happiness: </b><span id="happiness" ></span></p>
        <p><b>enthusiastic: </b><span id="enthusiastic"></span></p>
        <p><b>resilient: </b><span id="resilient" ></span></p>
        <p><b>optimistic: </b><span id="optimistic"></span></p>
        <p><b>wellness: </b><span id="wellness"></span></p>


        <script language="JavaScript">
              function processScore()
              {
                var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");

                var temp = parameters[0].split("=");
                h = unescape(temp[1]);
                temp = parameters[1].split("=");
                e = unescape(temp[1]);
                temp = parameters[2].split("=");
                r = unescape(temp[1]);
                temp = parameters[3].split("=");
                o = unescape(temp[1]);
                temp = parameters[4].split("=");
                w = unescape(temp[1]);
                document.getElementById("happiness").innerHTML = h;
                document.getElementById("enthusiastic").innerHTML = e;
                document.getElementById("resilient").innerHTML = r;
                document.getElementById("optimistic").innerHTML = o;
                document.getElementById("wellness").innerHTML = w;
              }
             processScore();
        </script>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            function checkradio() {
            if (document.getElementById("happiness").value == 1) {
            document.getElementById("H1").checked == true;
            } 
            else {
            document.getElementById("H2").checked == true;
            }
            }
        </script>
    <div>

</div>
    </body>
</html>
```